# Latex in Inkscape: error when writing

Tags: python, inkscape

I am trying to use Latex in Inkscape. After several installations, I am now able to see the Latex option in Extensions-> Render. However, when I tried to use it, I got the following error:

> The fantastic lxml wrapper for libxml2 is required by inkex.py and
>   therefore this extension. Please download and install the latest
>   version from http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/lxml/, or install it
>   through your package manager by a command like: sudo apt-get install
>   python-lxml
>   Technical details:
>   No module named lxml

So I followed the link and downloaded this file: 
lxml-3.6.0-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl (md5)

Any idea where I should place this file and if this is enough to make Latex work correctly ?